# UI changes triggering events vs. UI changes triggered programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Here is a problem I often come across:

I start building my app and define event handlers for changes in the UI, e.g. a user uses a select list -> event triggered -> event handled.

At some point I want to programmatically make changes to the UI and if those changes trigger events, handlers go off without any way of controlling them.

Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a smarter command implementation. Instead of having the logic directly in UI event handlers, you keep them dumb, and only executing certain tasks via command functions/classes/dispatcher/.. anything you want. Then prior to making your changes to UI, you can instruct command dispatcher to not run certain task, in any way suits you.